# What is RMI TCP Accept, Attach Listener, and Signal Dispatcher in Visual VM?

Tags: java, visualvm

I'm profiling a program with Visual VM. My program runs for a while and finally pops up a few plots using [XChart](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart) showing the results. After the charts are displayed, I noticed in Visual VM some active threads "RMI TCP Accept", "Attach Listener", and "Signal Dispatcher". What are these threads? I assume they are there in connection with Visual VM only. Am I correct??

[image: Screen shot from Visual VM]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Loosely answered by this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/7698906/573057

As you assume; Attach, Signal and RMI TCP Accept are for JMX monitoring by jConsole, VisualVM or similar.

The others are for garbage collection (e.g. Finalizer, Reference Handler).