# The "VM Periodic Task Thread" is run every 50 milliseconds, can I tune this?

Tags: jvm, raspberry-pi, jvm-arguments

On a normal hardware today this likely does not hurt ever, but on a Raspberry PI it is a bit annoying that the CPU is woken up every 50 milliseconds even for a java application which currently does absolutely nothing.

I verify with `strace`, that the "VM Periodic Task Thread" is active every 50 milliseconds. A rough answer of what it does is given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5259870/2954288), but can I tune the 50 milliseconds somehow?

Comment: Looks like you aren't running Java SE Embedded which is designed exactly for these kind of devices. Embedded version reduces some VM background activites, e.g. `UsePerfData`, `GuaranteedSafepointInterval`, `CleanChunkPoolAsync` etc.

Comment: Indeed not, just the plain jvm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try setting `-XX:PerfDataSamplingInterval=xxx`, the default is 50 and performance sampling matches the description you linked, so that might be it.

Comment: Looks like this did the trick. Looks like I need to read more about this sampling to figure out how high I can put the interval.